# Number to be incremented and then reset with each date

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have searched a lot on net and this forum. I found similar questions but it didn't answer my question.
What I need to do is that I need to generate a number which contains date,month,and then a serial number which needs to be reset with each new date.
For eg 280901 (28-date 09-month 01- serial number), 280902, 280903...
and then 290901 for the next date
I am new to VB. 
Please help!!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a formula. If you have your dates in column A and put this formula in column B to create the serial numbers:

```
=TEXT(A1,"DDMM")&TEXT(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1),"0#")
```

You will get the following:

```
28/09/2016  280901
28/09/2016  280902
28/09/2016  280903
28/09/2016  280904
29/09/2016  290901
29/09/2016  290902
29/09/2016  290903
29/09/2016  290904
```

Comment: Hi. There is no column for date. I need to do in macro VB

Comment: Where are the different dates stored then? Are you simply using today's date?

Comment: Ya I am using today's date

Comment: If you need to do it in a macro, what have you tried so far? - this isn't a free code writing service so you'll need to supply evidence of your own attempts first.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a free code writing service but to get you started you could try something like the following.

```
Dim iVal As Integer, tdate As String, serial as String
'sets todays date as string
tdate = Date

'counts how many serials there are for today and adds 1
iVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), "*" & tdate & "*") + 1

'creates new serial
serial = Date & " 000" & iVal

'just for this example it will put the new serial in column A
Range("A" & iVal).Value = serial
```